# Why would someone need an in-memory database?

Tags: database, in-memory-database

I read that a few databases can be used in-memory but can't think of  reason why someone would want to use this feature. I always use a database to persist data and memory caches for fast access.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When should I consider using a in memory database and what are the issue to look out for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1593692/when-should-i-consider-using-a-in-memory-database-and-what-are-the-issue-to-look)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Cache is also a kind of database, like a file system is. 'Memory cache' is just a specific application of an in-memory database and some in-memory databases are specialized as memory caches.

Other uses of in-memory databases have already been included in other answers, but let me enumerate the uses too:

1. Memory cache. Usually a database system specialized for that use (and probably known as 'a memory cache' rather than 'a database') will be used.
2. Testing database-related code. In this case often an 'in-memory' mode of some generic database system will be used, but also a dedicated 'in-memory' database may be used to replace other 'on-disk' database for faster testing.
3. Sophisticated data manipulation. In-memory SQL databases are often used this way. SQL is a great tool for data manipulation and sometimes there is no need to write the data on disk while computing the final result.
4. Storing of transient runtime state. There are application that need to store their state in some kind of database but do not need to persist that over application restart. Think of some kind of process manager – it needs to keep track of sub-processes running, but that data is only valid as long as the application and the sub-processes run.

Answer (score 18):

A common use case is to run unit/integration tests.

You don't really care about persisting data between each test run and you want tests to run as quickly as possible (to encourage people to do them often).  Hosting a database in process gives you very quick access to the data.

Comment: Never thought of this. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your time. I'll go with @Jacek Konieczny answer.

Answer (score 4):

Does your memory cache have SQL support?

How about you consider the in-memory database as a really clever cache?

That does leave questions of how the in-memory database gets populated and how updated are managed and consistency is preserved across multiple instances.

Comment: No the in-memory db doesn't have SQL support but not I am wondering if the savings in IO time wouldn't be offset somehow by overusing queries.

Comment: IO tends to be pretty expensive compared with in-memory actions, so I'd expect an in-memory db to perform well. I remember reading of someone (maybe Joel) who used a PC whose "disk" that was entirely in memory. Had lovely response time.

Answer (score 4):

Searching for something among 100000 elements is slow if you don't use tricks like indexes. Those tricks are already implemented in a database engine (be it persistent or in-memory).

A in-memory database might offer a more efficient search feature than what you might be able to implement yourself quickly over self-written structures.

Comment: That is very, very wrong. No in-memory database comes even close in performance to a well-written application specific data structure. You might not have the time or the expertise to create such a structure, though.

Answer (score 2):

In-memory databases are roughly at least an order of magnitude faster than traditional RDBMS for general purpose (read side) queries.  Most are disk backed providing the very same consistency as a normal RDBMS - only catch the entire dataset must fit into RAM.

The core idea is disk backed storage has huge random access penalties which does not apply to DRAM.  Data can be index/organized in a random access optimized way not feasible using traditional RDBMS data caching schemes.

Answer (score 1):

Applications, which require real time responses would like to use an in memory database, perhaps application to control aircraft, plants where the response time is critical

Answer (score 1):

An in memory database is also useful in game programming. You can store data in an in memory database which is much faster than permanent databases.

Answer (score 0):

They are used as an advanced data structure to store, query and modify runtime data.

Answer (score 0):

You may need a database if several different applications are going to access the dataset. A database has a consistent interface for accessing / modifying data, which your hash table (or whatever else you use) won't have.

If a single program is dealing with the data, then it's reasonable to just use a data structure in whatever language you are using though.

Comment: That is the database vision of the early '70s. Since then we've learned that integration through the (relational) database is an anti-pattern. It provides too much coupling and too little cohesion => a bug in one application brings down the whole system

Comment: @Stephan Eggermont - most integration techniques start looking like anti-patterns, once they start getting misused. There's no real holy grail for integration - it still needs coordination, which is where orgs really fall apart.

Answer (score 0):

In-memory database is better than performing database caching.
Database caching works similar to in-memory databases when it comes to READ operations.

On the other hand, when it comes to WRITE operations, in-memory databases are faster when compared to database caches, where the data is persisted onto disk (which leads to IO overhead).

Also, with database caching you can end with cache misses but you will never end up with cache misses when using in-memory databases.

Answer (score 0):

Given their speed and the declining price of RAM, it’s likely that in-memory databases will become the dominant technology in the future. There are already some that have developed sophisticated features like SQL queries, secondary indexes, and engines for processing datasets larger than RAM.