# Alternative to the TimesTen in memory database

Tags: .net, database, in-memory-database, timesten

> I just found "[Has anyone published a
>   detailed comparison between different
>   in-memory RDBMSs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/970022/has-anyone-published-a-detailed-comparison-between-different-in-memory-rdbmss)?" that is related
>   to my question.

[TimesTen](http://www.oracle.com/database/timesten.html) (see [also](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TimesTen)) is a [In-Memory Database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-memory_database#Commercial%5Fproducts) from oracle.

It has a lot going for it including.

- Fast, consistent response time
- High transaction throughput
- Standard SQL, no application rewrite
- Persistent and recoverable
- High availability and no data loss

However it is priced out of the reach of most people ([$41,500.00 / Processor](https://shop.oracle.com/pls/ostore/product?p1=oracletimesteninmemorydatabase&sc=ocom_oracletimesteninmemorydatabase#)).

So what alternatives are there, and what are there pros and cons.

(I am using .NET if it changes your answer)

Comment: Sybase introduced an in-memory database option with [ASE 15.5](http://www.sybase.com/products/databasemanagement/adaptiveserverenterprise/ase15-5).

Comment: Sybase also introduced an in-memory run-mode for SQL Anywhere 11.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A popular in-memory database system is McObject's eXtremeDB, see

http://www.mcobject.com/extremedbfamily.shtml

There is also a good white paper, offered for download from the home page of McObject's Web site, called, "In-Memory Database Systems: Myths and Facts". It clarifies some questions that arise when discussing the technology, such as, "how is an IMDS different from a 'traditional' database running on a RAM disk?"

Comment: I accepted this answer due to the pointer to the white paper.

Answer (score 6):

Above question was asked (and answered) way back in 2009. However, the question is still relevant and we can give a 2nd look.

I can suggest following alternatives to TimesTen:

- **SQLite**

  - Link: http://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html
  - Advantages: Small footprint, It's RDBMS (no application rewrite required)
  - Disadvantages: No row-level locking
- **H2**

  - Link: http://www.h2database.com/html/features.html#in_memory_databases
  - Advantages: It's RDBMS (no application rewrite required), row-level locking
- **HyperSQL**

  - Link: http://hsqldb.org/
  - Advantages & Disadvantages: Very similar to H2 (above).
- **Redis**

  - Link: http://redis.io
  - Advantages: Blazingly fast with native support for data structures like list, hash, set, sorted set etc
  - Disadvantages: Not an RDBMS (you may have to rewrite your application)

All of the above can run **in-memory**. Features-wise you might find things missing as compared to TimesTen. But they are certainly worth a look.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, in this field people also look at kdb from [Kx Systems](http://kx.com/).  I think both these systems really had they hay-day in the early 2000's.  I would see if a tuned MySQL with a solid state RAID array would give you the performance you need.

BTW, I once wrote a time series database which outperformed both TimesTen and Kdb.  It supported a SQL-92 syntax.  The key to the performance was binding the schema to C++ template based classes, and using memory mapped files.  Allowing for on-the-run schema changes is quite expensive, and defining the schema at compile time, data lookups could be retrieved in just a few assembly instructions.

Comment: In-memory databases are generally designed to be "in memory (RAM)" vs. "in SSD"... However, would you care to elaborate on the design of your time series database? I know people who would be very interested if its design is significantly better than both TimesTen and KDB.

Answer (score 2):

I asked this question a **LONG** time ago, these days Microsoft SQL Server have "[In-Memory OLTP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dn133186.aspx)" that is a memory-optimized database engine integrated into the SQL Server engine.  It is not cheap, but seems to be **very fast** for some workloads.

Answer (score 2):

Another for the list: open-source [Tarantool](https://www.tarantool.org) is a persistent in-memory option that like TimesTen supports ACID transactions and SQL. Unlike TimesTen, though, it can be auto-sharded and also features a full Lua application server for stored procedures.

Answer (score 1):

I have recently done a comparison betweem Oracle TimesTen and Sybase ASE IMDB.

The article is in two parts and available from the following links.

http://searchoracle.techtarget.com/tip/In-memory-databases-Oracle-TimesTen-vs-Sybase-ASE

http://searchoracle.techtarget.com/tip/In-memory-databases-Oracle-TimesTen-vs-Sybase-ASE-part-2

Answer (score 0):

An alternative may be solidDB, a comparison between the two may be found here: [TimesTen and solidDB comparison](http://bigdatamatters.com/bigdatamatters/2009/12/oracle_ibm_database_comparison.html)

Answer (score 0):

Add to the list of In-Mem databases.

Apache Derby
HyperSQL or HSQLDB.

H2 and HyperSQL have compatibility mode as well to support schema of other databases, which is a very nice feature.